# Use Woocommerce functions in custom php files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am a total beginner in programming with PHP. I wanted to create a PHP file in which the `order_status` from a predefined order (in my case 108) gets changed to completed.

Therefore I need the woocommerce functions `get_order($ID)` and `update_status` but I do not know how to use them in my PHP. I hope you understand my problem. From Java I could imagine that I need to get an instance from a class or something like that?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php $ord = new WC_Order(108); $ord->update_status('completed'); ?>
```

When I open the page I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Order' not found (...)
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: Hi Leopold, this is what I have so far: 

<?php  
$ord = new WC_Order(108); 
$ord->update_status('completed');
?> 


When I open the page I receive the following error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Order' not found (...)

Comment: In what file are you putting this code? I’m trying to figure what libraries of code have been included.

Comment: Hi Will! I put the code in a .php file called completor.php
It is located in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/completor.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general on Wordpress/WooCommerce you will include your functions code:

- In your active child theme (or active theme) `function.php` file
- In a plugin…

You can also enable some code in:

- Your theme templates
- WooCommerce templates that you will [override through your active child theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) *(or active theme)*.

> Now to execute that function, you will need an event that will execute your function.

In *(Wordpress)* Woocommerce there is a lot of [action hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) that are triggered on some specific events that you can use to execute your function. In this case **your function will be hooked** *(ready to be executed on a specific event)*.

*If you want to change the status of a specific order is better to do it in the related order edit page in backend.*

**An example:**

For example you can change the order status when a customer has submit his order after checkout on `order-received` end point (thankyou page):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order');
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // Change order status to "completed"
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

This code is an official code snippet: [Automatically Complete Orders](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automatically-complete-orders/).

It is a good example that shows you how things can work… So in your case you are using here [`WC_Order` class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) methods like `update_status()`.

Now with this code base, you can refine the behaviors like in this answer: 
[WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)

---

Related to orders: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand much more. I have the following problem: I wrote a programm that fullfills my orders from woocommerce. It changes the order_status directly via sql to completed. The problem is that the email trigger won't be triggered using this way. So I decided to write all fullfilled orders in a new table in my database and add a cronjob which opens a php page every 10 minutes. In this php I wanted to get all id's from the table and set the order_status from them to completed. My event would only be that the page is opened. How can I add this as a hook? Philipp

Comment: @PhilippRitter Just send you a mail, related to this…